# Laravel Handling radio button values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I have a dynamically formed table with radio buttons to choose pass or fail in each rows. Below are my codes:

```
<form name="form2" method="post" action="/admin/testresults/update/added">
  <?php if(isset($rows)){ $i=1; $pass=$ fail='' ; foreach ($rows as $row) { (($row->result == 1) ? $pass='checked' : $fail='checked'); print "
  <tr>
    <td>".$i."</td>
    <td>".$row->name." ".$row->last_name."</td>
    <td>
      <input type='radio' name='".$row->userId."' value='1' ".$pass.">Pass
      <br/>
      <input type='radio' name='".$row->userId."' value='0' ".$fail.">Fail
      <input type='hidden' name='".$row->userId."' value='".$row->userId."' </td>
  </tr>
  "; $i++; } print "
  <tr>
    <td colspan='3'>
      <input class='ember-view btn btn-danger' type='submit' />
    </td>
  </tr>"; } ?>
</form>
```

I'm using the below codes in my controller:

```
$inputs = Input::get();
foreach($inputs as $input){
    TestResults::updateCandidate($input);
}
```

What I want to pass into updateCandidate() is the student id and the selected radio button value (1/0). How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: are you using Laravel? And if so, why are you embedding PHP code into a template?

Comment: @Cheluis I'm still new to Laravel... not really sure what are the good practices

Comment: `TestResults::updateCandidate($input)` look like a custom class you defined. How do you want to pass the parameters into it? as an array?  as individual strings?

Comment: That's fine, frameworks, are intended to avoid using boilerplate code like this. You should read how to render forms and templates in Laravel, is not that complicated. Although, IMHO, Laravel's documentation is not the best one, you can check about views and templates in here. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates.

Comment: @MichaelColeman I was hoping it would pass as an array. But as far as I know, all the values of each rows can be received using  `$inputs = Input::get()`

Comment: @Cheluis thanks for your suggestion. Will definitely read more documentations to enhance my knowledge in using Laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I agree with @Chelius comments, look at laravel's documentation around blade templating and @if / @foreach and the use of {{ Form::input }}.

However in answer to your question - you will need to name you inputs better to retrieve the user id and the verbose PHP version should end up looking like this:

```
<td>
  <input type='radio' name='results[".$row->userId."]' value='1' ".$pass.">Pass
  <br/>
  <input type='radio' name='results[".$row->userId."]' value='0' ".$fail.">Fail
  <input type='hidden' name='".$row->userId."' value='".$row->userId."'
 </td>
```

When processing, your code should then be:

```
$inputs = Input::get();
foreach($inputs['results'] as $userId => $result){
    TestResults::updateCandidate($userId, $result);
}
```

Note that you may need to update your "updateCandidate" function to accept the user id and the result.